# Finding the maximum absolute value whilst preserving + or - symbol

Tags: r, matrix

If I have a matrix:

```
mat=matrix(c(-21,14,28,17,-16,-9,-17,-30,18), nrow=3)
mat
          [,1]   [,2]  [,3]
     [1,]  -21     17    17
     [2,]   14    -16   -30
     [3,]   28     -9    18
```

I can isolate the highest absolute value simply with

```
max(abs(mat))
```

However how do I preserve the sign so I return -30? 
For some context, I have a large number of matrices and I need a command to isolate the highest absolute number in all of them including the sign (some will be positive others negative).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need the index of the value in the matrix which is the maximum absolute value, which you can then use to return the value itself. `which.max` will do this (and `which.min` for the opposite):

```
mat[which.max( abs(mat) )]
# [1] -30
```

Comment: You *could* make it more complicated :-) by doing `amat<-abs(mat);smat<-sign(mat); amat[max(amat)]*smag[max(amat)]` . But rather obviously I wouldn't recommend doing so!

Answer (score 10):

Building on Simon's answer. If you wanted a function that returned the absolute max for a vector or a matrix, you could use the following:

```
absmax <- function(x) { x[which.max( abs(x) )]}
```

E.g.,

```
> absmax(c(-10, 0, 9))
[1] -10
```

Comment: I like the function, however it does not always return a single value. But since a proper ties.method (as in base::rank) is not feasible in this context, I'd just make it retrun the first absmax-value: `absmax <- function(x) { x[which.max( abs(x) )][1]}`